# Redefining command outside math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros

In `LaTeX2e`, Is it possible to redefine a command, yet have the scope of the redefinition apply itself only outside math mode? For instance, I'd like to redefine `\sec` to `\section`, but unfortunately `\sec` has a special meaning inside math mode (one that [doesn't look exceptionally useful](http://www.ntg.nl/doc/biemesderfer/ltxcrib.pdf), yet still exists), which I would like to preserve when entering said mode.

Comment: Doen't stick a screwdriver in your knee. Use a decent editor assisting you in your daily work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. How would a different editor choice help with this?

Comment: You wanna be efficient and save time, right? Redefining LaTeX macros isn't the way to go. Getting a powerful editor is.

Comment: Most editors are aware of the `\section` command and are able to give prominence to it or use it for code folding. Going the `\sec` route means giving up with these features.

Comment: Now I understand, it's all about allowing auto-completion features of editors like TexMaker. Yes, I completely agree that such simple redefinitions are agnostic towards the presence of such features. Yet it is also the case that I tend to collaborate on .tex sources with people that use various editors on different OSs. I can therefore not safely rely on assumptions about editor functionality, and would rather incorporate cross-platform capacity by virtue of command definitions and redefinitions.

Comment: If you collaborate with various peoples it is not a good idea to use new names for standard commands like section. You force them to learn two names for the same thing. Also if they use decent editors loose highlighting and so the source is less readable for them.

Comment: Those are all correct comments. I have decided to return the document to its original form. At the very least, we have a thread that explains how one can limit the scope of a redefining inside or outside math mode.

Answer (score 3):

## Can it be done?

What you ask can technically be done, with some care.

First you have to define a macro equivalent to the current `\sec`; in this particular case, `\let\latexsec=\sec` is good (provided it is issued after `amsmath` is loaded).

Second, you can redefine `\sec`. The first attempt,

```
\renewcommand{\sec}{\relax\ifmmode\latexsec\else\expandafter\section\fi}
```

fails as soon as `\sec` appears in a sectional title, be it `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection` and so on, say

```
\section{Definition of $\sec$}
```

This is because LaTeX tries to write out the title in the `.aux` file, but when the write operation occurs, TeX is in no mode, so `\ifmmode` is false and `\sec` then expands to `\section`, which is not something one would like to try.

Second attempt:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sec}{%
  \ifmmode\latexsec\else\expandafter\section\fi
}
```

this seems to work, because `\sec` in the title is not expanded during the write operation, having been made robust. However, we soon find another cause for failure, when `hyperref` is loaded. This happens because the package tries to use the title for the bookmarks.

This can be cured by adding

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\sec{sec }}
```

so this local redefinition overrides the standard one when the bookmarks are being produced.

Final code (to be added in the preamble after all packages have been loaded):

```
\let\latexsec\sec
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sec}{%
  \ifmmode\latexsec\else\expandafter\section\fi
}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
  {\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\sec{sec }}}
  {}
\makeatother
```

## Why shouldn't it be done?

There are several reason against doing this. One is general: a consistent user interface doesn't use the same command name for doing very different things.

Actually even Knuth has sinned in this respect, because the primitive `\span` means different things in different contexts (there are reasons for doing this, and the primitive is to be used with care anyway, usually hidden in other macros).

Another reason is for the particular case. Abbreviating `\section` into `\sec` has many disadvantages for no apparent advantage, other than saving a few keystrokes.

Smart editors know about `\section` and most colorize it with special colors for better readability of the source code. But some of them also have code folding features: one can press a button and all text pertaining to sections different from the one we're working on is hidden, leaving only the section title with some marker denoting the folded text.

If you use `\sec`, you're giving up with these useful features.

Another reason: if you work in cooperation with other people, they probably won't use `\sec` as they're used to `\section`. The result will be an inconsistent document and email exchanges about “what the h*** is `\sec` doing?”

Keep it simple and don't try saving on keystrokes. Good text editors will have code completion: type `\sec` and you'll be presented with possible completions, including the braces and the cursor between them if you choose `\section`.