# Redefine \or form within a nested if statement?

Tags: tex-core

It's apparently a bad idea to redefine `\or` so that it renders as `\lor` in mathmode. However, while trying anyhow, I faced two issues that I would like to understand better.
I followed the approach [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197194/redefining-and-in-math-mode), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275331/redefining-command-outside-math-mode)

```
\let\@oldor\or
\def\or{\ifmmode\lor\else\expandafter\@oldor\fi}
```

However, after moving that into another if statement (checking the [package option](https://github.com/ag-gipp/texvc-latex/commit/537ef5491e3e9c56a46b2ced5df3ac04ad4f2223) overwrite `\or`) it stopped working. Instead,  I got the `! Extra \or.` error.

By chance, I discovered that I get the same error when I'm trying to use `\verb|\or|` in a footnote [(overleaf)](https://www.overleaf.com/14275904mksnhxgmjtpv#/55033228/).

Any chance how I can rewrite the `\def` without the expandafter, so that it works anywhere, no matter how many if statements are nested?

Comment: If you redefine `\or`, then any conditional based on `\ifcase` will cease to work, no matter how you do the definition. Note that `\verb` is illegal in a footnote, with any contents.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please edit your question to provide a complete minimal example which produces the error you report, together with the complete text of the error message?

Comment: Although, as egreg says, this is essentially a doomed project.

Comment: You cn't use `\verb` in a footnote regardless of whether you have `\or` in it. `\footnote{\verb|or|}` fails too, albeit with a different error. The problem here is something like putting fragile code in a moving argument, although I'm not sufficiently knowledgeable to be able to explain exactly what that means :(.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You can't redefine `\or`.

**Longer answer**

Consider this plain TeX example:

```
\let\originalor\or
\def\or{\ifmmode\lor\else\expandafter\originalor\fi}

$a\or b$ (works)

\ifcase1
  0\or
  1\or
  2\else
  BUMMER\fi

\let\or\originalor

\ifcase1
  0\or
  1\or
  2\else
  BUMMER\fi

\bye
```

Guess what you get from the two `\ifcase` statements. Yes, the first one yields “BUMMER”, while the other one, with `\or` restored to its primitive meaning, yields the expected 1.

Why is that? In order to skip the cases, TeX *needs* to see the *primitive* `\or` (a control sequence let to the primitive `\or` would do as well). So if you redefine `\or`, ***no*** macro based on `\ifcase` will work as expected.

Well, they will work, but only when the tested integer is 0, because in this case TeX will expand the redefined `\or`, finding `\originalor` and so skipping up to the matching `\fi`. In the “BUMMER” case, the whole `0\or 1\or 2` counts as the text for the 0 case (because there is no primitive `\or` in it).

This is essentially the same as redefining `\fi` or any other conditional.

Comment: Thanks. That explains my observations and it gives new ideas how I can approach the larger problem: Rendering \or as \lor in mathmode. I have two ideas: 1) try to redefine the primitive or when math mode is started and restore it when math mode is left. 2) read the tex book and understand how Tex works

Comment: @physikerwelt 2 is a possibility but don't try 1: things will break.

Comment: @physikerwelt: before trying 1) you should check e.g. in amsmath.sty how often `\ifcase` with `\or` is used in math mode.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks. However, given the large list of [required package](https://github.com/ag-gipp/texvc-latex/blob/master/texvc.dtx#L28-L41) and 7 million formulae to process I will probably do some preprocessing and postpone the deeper understanding of the math processing of TeX to a later point in time.

Comment: @physikerwelt I don't understand your remark. I only wanted to make clear that you can't redefine `\or` in math mode as it is heavily used there too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ok. I got you wrong. I was trying to say even if there were only a few in amsmath there might be more in amsfonts or so. Thus we fully agree here.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to point out something that may be obvious (and in your case you've surely considered already), but is often ignored: if your desire is simply that you'd like to type `\or` in your personal `.tex` file or in formulas, and have it treated as if you'd typed `\lor`, then you can do this by processing the input (specifically, the parts entered manually by you or the user) externally, rather than via a TeX macro.

(For simplicity of illustration let's assume you want `\or` treated as `\lor` everywhere in your input file, not just in math mode. The example below shows that redefining `\or` only in math mode can also cause issues, so there's not much to gain by treating math mode specially anyway.)

Concretely, consider the following input file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\let\@oldor\or
\def\or{\ifmmode\lor\else\expandafter\@oldor\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{equation}
(x < 0) \or (x = 0) \or (x > 0)
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
\allowdisplaybreaks[1]
a &= b \\
c &= d
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

It fails with a hard-to-debug error on reaching the `\end{align}` line, because `\allowdisplaybreaks` uses `\or` internally. See the following from `amsmath.sty`:

```
\interdisplaylinepenalty\@M
\newcommand{\allowdisplaybreaks}[1][4]{%
  \interdisplaylinepenalty\getdsp@pen{#1}\relax
}
\def\getdsp@pen#1{%
  \ifcase #1\@M \or 9999 \or 6999 \or 2999 \or \z@\fi
}
```

Instead of redefinining `\or` in TeX, we can get rid of the redefinition (the part inside `\makeatletter … \makeatother` above), and simply replace every occurrence of `\or` with `\lor` with an external script. (E.g. something like `sed 's/\\or\([^a-zA-Z]\)/\\lor\1/g'` on your file will do.)

With LuaTeX (if our setup allows using that, which in your Mediawiki-texvc case probably not) we can do this inside the file itself if we want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer',
                           function(line)
                              return line:gsub([[\or([^a-zA-Z])]], [[\lor%1]])
                           end,
                           [[Replaces each \or in the input with \lor]])
```

```latex
\end{luacode*}

\begin{equation}
(x < 0) \or (x = 0) \or (x > 0)
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
\allowdisplaybreaks[1]
a &= b \\
c &= d
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Unlike the earlier version, this doesn't cause any issues from uses of `\or` in macros that were defined earlier.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. That was exactly the direction in which I wanted to go next. My idea was to hoop into the 'parsing' part of tex and change the tokens consumed in math mode.